# Export Flash as Transparent MOV

Tags: wpf, flash, video

Is it possible to export a flash movie with a transparent background as a .MOV.

I don't mean for embedding in a website, I mean the actual .MOV (or .avi).

What I'm trying to accomplish is that I have a flash animation that I want to embed in a WPF application.  I don't want to use a Browser within the WPF because of all of the issues that surround the browser control (has to be topmost control, etc).

So my solution was to export said animation as a movie and play it in the MediaElement control.  The only problem is that I need the background to be transparent, and I can't find a way to do this.

Any suggestions or alternative solutions would be most welcome.

Comment: in the Flash IDE: File > Export > Export Movie > ...choose Quicktime format > tick 'Ignore stage color(generate alpha channel)' and you're done. This works for actionscript generated graphics too. Not much code there.

Comment: Fantastic ... thanks ... can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as correct (for records sake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment above:

in the Flash IDE:

**File > Export > Export Movie > ...choose Quicktime format > tick 'Ignore stage color(generate alpha channel)'** 
and you're done.

This works for actionscript generated graphics too. Not much code there.

Comment: There are a couple more 'gotchas' you may need to look out for. 1/ I think you need to have QuickTime Pro installed (not 100% sure but know I needed it in the past). 2/ Choose a compression type that allows 'Millions of Colours+' in the Depth field. The plus means including the alpha channel. (I use Animation as my setting). 3/ In your edit program you may need to edit the properties to select premultiplied alpha (in Sony Vegas you need to bring the clip onto the timeline and select the alpha there).

Comment: I didn't run into those issues on osx, although I don't have QuickTime Pro. Since QuickTime (Pro or otherwise) doesn't come bundled with Windows I imagine there are a few extra steps to consider. Thanks for sharing these tips Das123 !

Comment: Ahh. I'm using Windows 7. Years ago I needed to animate a character with lip-synch and flash was the easiest way to do this. I had to get QT Pro to get it to work. I'm not sure if I needed it to get the export working or to get the alpha working in the editor (in Premier Pro at that time).

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting thing that worked! In the dialogue box you need to change the type of export to 'animation' if you have made an animation. Simply ticking 'ignore stage colour' did not work until I had changed the type of .mov to a animation.